# Refine String using Python/Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regular-language

please help me with refining this string using python/regex.
It also have large whitespaces.

```
/**
         * this is comment                this is comment
         * this is comment
         * <blank line>
         *      this is comment
         * this is comment
         * <blank line>
         * this is comment
         */
```

how to get a plain text by removing /**, *

I expect the output string should be :

this is comment 
this is comment 
this is comment 
this is comment 
this is comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sub()` function from the `RegEx` module to match unwanted characters and format the input string. Here's a proof of concept which gives the output you want. You can test it here: https://repl.it/@glhr/regex-fun

```
import re

inputStr = """/**
         * this is comment                this is comment
         * this is comment
         * 
         *      this is comment
         * this is comment
         * 
         * this is comment
         */"""

formattedStr = re.sub("[*/]", "", inputStr) # comments
formattedStr = re.sub("\n\s{2,}|\s{2,}", "\n", formattedStr) # extra whitespaces
formattedStr = re.sub("^\n+|\n+$|\n{2,}", "", formattedStr) # extra blank lines
print(formattedStr)
```

You can experiment with regular expressions on sites like https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 2):

As it is clear now that OP expected that comment `this is comment` six times, hence I suggest using this regex,

```
^[ /*]+\n?| {2,}(.*(\n))
```

And replace it with `\2\1`.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/biB7y2/4)**

Also, you really don't need three separate regex (as other accepted answer) to achieve this, instead it can be done using just a single regex.

Here is a Python code demo,

```
import re

s = '''/**
         * this is comment                this is comment
         * this is comment
         * 
         *      this is comment
         * this is comment
         * 
         * this is comment
         */'''

print(re.sub(r'(?m)^[ /*]+\n?| {2,}(.*(\n))', r'\2\1', s))
```

Prints following and notice I have enabled multiline mode using `(?m)` before the regex as suggested by [FailSafe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7623020/failsafe) and many thanks to him for suggesting it as it wasn't otherwise noticeable,

```
this is comment
this is comment
this is comment
this is comment
this is comment
this is comment
```

Let me know if you need explanation of any part in my answer.

Comment: Dude, please mention that this needs to operate in `Multiline` mode

Comment: @FailSafe: The demo link has it enabled already but I think mentioning it explicitly should have been better.

Comment: Yes. Given the simplicity of the task, I don't think the poster knows when to use Multiline. And I have to bolster that again, with the fact that he accepted the other answer XD

Comment: @FailSafe: Yes agree. Actually OP's post is a little incorrect. In his post his expected output lists `this is comment` five times where as he actually expected it six times as can be seen in expected answer, which is why I think he didn't accept my answer but that's not my fault :). Also when I posted this answer I was in a little hurry else I always give a demo code solution too. The other answer uses three different substitution otherwise it can be done in a single substitution with this regex. [Check Demo](https://regex101.com/r/biB7y2/4)

Comment: @"Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi" Yes definitely. I saw the mistake and wondered if he wanted it broken out, but that was negligible. Still, I'm +1'ing yours, but just want to ask you to edit it s it mentioned that multiline needs to be enabled.

Comment: @FailSafe: Thanks for upvote :) I appreciate you giving time to read my answer. I've updated my answer with a regex that gives correct output of listing comment six times and also gave python code solution, enabling multiline mode too and mentioning it specifically as you suggested and you were right indeed. People generally tend to miss such small attributes.

Comment: @"Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi" Holy crap. Re.Sub substitutes on the fly!! I spent like the last half hour trying to figure out how you got `\         * this is comment                
          this is comment` to print on separate lines. Wow. I learned something new.

Comment: @FailSafe: Yes it does and my solution exploits that well to get the desired results and hence is a little non-trivial.